# File upload control get file name

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the difference between the 2 lines below? They do the same thing so is there any difference ?

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
string filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

First one returns the file name from a given path. Second one returns the full path name including directory path

From [MSDN - GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path, result);

// This code produces output similar to the following: 
// 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\myfile.ext') returns 'myfile.ext' 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\') returns ''
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one gets filename from the path, but second one will directly give the uploaded filename via upload control `PostedFile`  property whose properties have information about uploaded file like name,size and extension .

I suggest to use second one, no need of System.IO as control has property which returns filename.